# Is there a way to find values that exist in all sheets in an excel workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel workbook that has 60 tabs.  I need to remove any value that exists in all of the tabs.  Is there a function or some way I could do this?

Comment: Tough one. I'd imagine you'd need to write some VBA to loop through all worksheets, find the worksheet with the fewest number of populated cells, then for each populated cell on that sheet, loop through all cells on other worksheets (until it can't find the value - meaning you can move on to checking the next populated cell)

Comment: Is there more than one value in a single cell ??

Comment: I've never created a loop before, but that kind of makes sense.  I did find this site which might be able to walk me through it: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html.                                                                                                                                                                                                  There is a name of a charge name in one column and a code (numbers) in another.  I could do the search off of either.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear exactly what you're trying to do - delete every used cell in all worksheets? Delete one specified value from every worksheet? Delete a value if it exists on ALL the worksheets?

Comment: Delete a value if it exists on ALL the worksheets. Thanks everyone for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options; one option would be to use a formula to see if the value exists on all worksheets, then manually use a find/replace to remove it if it does. I'm not a fan of this option.

My recommendation would be to use a macro with a For Each loop to loop through all the worksheets in the file and check to see if the value was found; if it's found in all the sheets, clear those cells. We'll do something like this:

```
Sub ClearAll()
    Const csValue As String = "Test"    'This is the value we're looking for


    Dim rngFound() As Range 'This is a list of all the cells containing the value
    Dim i As Integer    'This is a counter for the list
    Dim shtSheet As Worksheet   'This is an individual sheet
    Dim bolAll As Boolean   'This is a flag to indicate whether the value is in all sheets


    ReDim rngFound(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)    'Size the list to the number of sheets
    bolAll = True   'Assume we will find the value in all sheets
    For Each shtSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets  'Loop through each sheet
        Set rngFound(shtSheet.Index) = shtSheet.Cells.Find(what:=csValue) 'Look for the value in this worksheet
        If rngFound(shtSheet.Index) Is Nothing Then 'Check whether a match was found
            bolAll = False  'If a match wasn't found, change the flag and exit the loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next shtSheet

    If bolAll Then  'If the value was on all sheets
        For i = 1 To UBound(rngFound)   'Loop through each flagged cell...
            rngFound(i).ClearContents   '...and delete its contents
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

To use this code, open the Visual Basic Editor either by hitting Alt+F11 on the keyboard, or by going to the Developer tab of the ribbon and choosing "Visual Basic". In the left-hand pane of the Visual Basic editor, right-click on your worksheet's entry and choose "Insert" -> "Module:

[image]

Copy the code above and paste it into the new module window. You can now access it and run it from your Macros interface. You will want to replace the "Test" on the second line of this code with whatever value you're looking for. We have other ways of changing that value as well, if you need to do this with multiple values - let me know what you need.